# How to calculate probability for tennis match?

Tags: probability

After reading all the topics, a large number of information, I did not find an intelligible answer to this question.
For weak tournaments, the probabilities are calculated only according to the statistics of past games, I confirm this 100%.
Since I am not a mathematician, I cannot fully reveal this topic, so I turned here for help, I hope someone will be interested in this topic.
I selected several games so that each of the players had a minimum number of past games (for convenient calculation).

**Player1 vs Player2. 23.09.2017. Bookie opening odds for player1 = 1.25, player2 = 3.75, margin 6.67%. Chances without margin for player1=~75%, player2=~25%.(We will assume that the margin is equally distributed).**

Previous statistics for player1 below:

| Players | Date | Court | Result | Sets | Games |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unknown vs **Player1** | 22.04.2017 | Clay | Loose | 2 - 0 | 6-4, 6-3 |

Previous statistics for player2 below:

| Players | Date | Court | Result | Sets | Games |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unknown vs **Player2** | 22.04.2017 | Clay | Loose | 2 - 0 | 6-0, 6-2 |
| Unknown vs **Player2** | 15.04.2017 | Clay | Loose | 2 - 0 | 6-1, 6-2 |
| Unknown vs **Player2** | 09.04.2017 | Clay | Loose | 2 - 0 | 6-0, 6-0 |
| **Player2** vs Unknown | 08.04.2017 | Clay | Win | 2 - 1 | 6-4, 5-7, 6-3 |

I tried various methods to get such probabilities, but since I have little knowledge in the theory of probability, I used simple methods, which I will describe below:

**1) Tried to get the probabilities using the number of sets.**
$$Player1 Win Set = 0, Player1 Loose Set = 2, Player2 Win Set = 2, Player2 Loose Set = 7$$
$$Player1 Probability = (P1WinSet+P2LooseSet)/(P1WinSet+P1LooseSet+P2WinSet+P2LooseSet)$$
$$Player1 Probability = (0+7)/(0+2+2+7) = 0.6363$$
**2) Tried to get the probabilities using the number of games.**
$$Player1 Win Game = 7, Player1 Loose Games = 12, Player2 Win Games = 22, Player2 Loose Games = 50$$
$$Player1 Probability = (P1WinGames+P2LooseGames)/(P1WinGames+P1LooseGames+P2WinGames+P2LooseGames)$$
$$Player1 Probability = (7+50)/(7+12+22+50) = 0.6263$$
**3) Tried to get the probabilities using the number of matches.**
$$Player1 Win Match = 0, Player1 Loose Match = 1, Player2 Win Match = 1, Player2 Loose Match = 3$$
$$Player1 Probability = (P1WinMatch+P2LooseMatch)/(P1WinMatch+P1LooseMatch+P2WinMatch+P2LooseMatch)$$
$$Player1 Probability = (0+3)/(0+1+1+3) = 0.6$$

It is interesting that if we do not take the game won by player2, which was on 04/08/2017, then the results will be as follows:

1. Using sets (0+6)/(0+2+0+6) = 0.75
2. Using games (7+36)/(7+12+5+36) = 0.7166
3. Using matches (0+3)/(0+1+0+3) = 0.75

This option almost coincides with the bookmaker’s probabilities, but I don’t understand the logic why we don’t take the won match of player2...

**Anyone who knows the theory of probability and mathematics, could you list the methods by which you can try to get probabilities like a bookmaker based on the data I provided? Or maybe you know how he does it?**